# django model dropdown missing in html view

Tags: python, html, django, redirect, django-models

I'm writing a django app, and I'd like for users to be able to select a [team_number] from a dropdown menu, then when they hit submit be redirected to a page that renders out the database information associated with that selection. I'm using the redirect class View, but the problem I'm having is that there is no dropdown menu showing up to select [team_number] from on the html page team-stats.html.

**views.py:**

```
class TeamStatsView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'team-stats.html',
                      {'team_number': TeamStats()})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        team_number = TeamStats(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if team_number.is_valid():
            # do stuff & add to database
            team_number.save()
            team_number = TeamStats.objects.create()
            # use my_file.pk or whatever attribute of FileField your id is
            # based on
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/team-stats/%i/' % team_number.pk)
        return render(request, 'team-stats.html', {'team_number': team_number})
```

**models.py:**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_number = models.IntegerField()
    team_notes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.team_number)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teams'
        app_label = 'frcstats'
```

**forms.py:**

```
class TeamStats(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['team_number']
```

**team-stats.html:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ TeamStatsView }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If there are any other files that I need to update into here to show what I'm trying to do, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your view variable name to team_numbers and replacing your team-stats.html snippet with the following:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="teams">
    {% for team_number in team_numbers %}
        <option value="{{ team_number }}">Team Num: {{ team_number }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Then update your view to:

```
class TeamStatsView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'team-stats.html',
            {'team_numbers':Team.objects.values('team_number')})
```

Comment: Doing this at least creates a dropdown in the html view, but it isn't populated by anything, it's just an empty dropdown

Comment: That means there is nothing in your team_numbers view variable. I believe you can query these using the query set:

`Team.objects.values('team_number')`

Make sure you import the Team model into your view

Comment: I'm confused, where would that query go? It should be showing the 777 entries I have in my database under team_number. The Team model is imported already because it's used in a separate view

Comment: @alicen I updated my answer to reflect the changes needed for the TeamStatsView

Comment: S -- this worked perfectly, except that for the dropdown it isn't showing the values from my database for team_number, it lists them all as "Team Num: {'team_number': 120}" , though it does change the number correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use choices=NUMBERS

```
NUMBERS = (
    ('1','1'),
    ('2','2'),
    ('3','3'),
    ('4','4')
)
class Team(models.Model):
    team_number = models.IntegerField(choices=NUMBERS )
    team_notes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.team_number)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teams'
        app_label = 'frcstats'
```

Comment: I don't want to use options like this because it's a database with a few thousand numbers to choose from

Answer (score 0):

Your view variable is called `team_number`.
Try to change `TeamStatsView` into `team_number`:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ team_number }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That worked to add an integer input, though not a dropdown list of what's in my database. Also, it seems that the help I had before on the views.py file may be wrong because it's trying to save to the database a new entry instead of using the selection to pull information from the database and show it

Comment: Are the options fixed? Then you should consider to ad `choices` to your model field. Otherwise go with @Nick-s answer